# A strategy for parsing a tab-separated file

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, text-files

What would be the most primitive way of parsing  a tab-separated file in Java, so that the tabular data would not lose the structure? I am **not** looking for a way to do it with Bean or Jsoup, since they are not familiar to me, **a beginner**. I need advice on what would be the logic behind it and what would be the efficient way to do it, for example if I have a table like

```
ID reference | Identifier    | Type 1| Type 2  | Type 3 |
1            | red#01        | 15%   |  20%    | 10%    |
2            | yellow#08     | 13%   |  20%    | 10%    |
```

Correction: In this example I have Types 1 - 3, but my question applies to N  number of types.

Can I achieve table parsing by just using arrays or is there a different data structure in Java that would be better for this task? This is how I think I should do it:

1. Scan/read the first line splitting at `"\t"` and create a String array.
2. Split that array into sub-arrays of 1 table heading per sub-array
3. Then, start reading the next line of the table, and for each sub-array, add the corresponding values from the columns.

Does this plan sound right or am I overcomplicating things/being completely wrong? Is there an easier way to do it? (provided that I still don't know how to split arrays into subarrays and how to populate the subarrays with the values from the table)

Comment: The easiest way to do it is using a bean and a flat file reading library. You will have to learn how to do this at some point, so do so. How do you plan to write more complex code? Always reinvent wheels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would **strongly** suggest you use a read flat file parsing library for this, like the excellent [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

Failing that, here is a solution in Java 8.

First, create a class to represent your data:

```
static class Bean {

    private final int id;
    private final String name;
    private final List<Integer> types;

    public Bean(int id, String name, List<Integer> types) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.types = types;
    }

    //getters 

}
```

Your suggestion to use various lists is very scripting based. Java is OO so you should use that to your advantage.

Now we just need to parse the file:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Path path = Paths.get("path", "to", "file.tsv");
    final List<Bean> parsed;
    try (final Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
        parsed = lines.skip(1).map(line -> line.split("\\s*\\|\\s*")).map(line -> {
            final int id = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
            final String name = line[1];
            final List<Integer> types = Arrays.stream(line).
                    skip(2).map(t -> Integer.parseInt(t.replaceAll("\\D", ""))).
                    collect(Collectors.toList());
            return new Bean(id, name, types);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

In essence the code skips the first line then loops over lines in the file and for each line:

1. Split the line on the delimiter - seems to be `|`. This requires regex so you need to escape the pipe as it is a special character. Also we consume any spaces before/after the delimiter.
2. Create a `new Bean` for each line by parsing the array elements.
3. First parse the id to an `int`
4. Next get the name
5. Finally get a `Stream` of the lines, skip the first two elements, and parse the remaining to a `List<Integer>`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what if I have more than 3 types, but 100 or more - what would I have to do then?

Comment: @nanachan You should have made that plain in your question. Then you just store a `List<Integer>` in the `Bean`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use Apache Commons CSV package, like described on the homepage: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Guava's Splitter and Table:

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Splitter

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table